# Node unable to run compiles TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following TypeScript

```
var foo = (...myParams) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < myParams.length; i++){
        console.log(myParams[i] + " ");
    }
};

foo('a', 'b', 'c');
```

However, when it's compiled by WebStorm finds errors in the compiled code:

[image: WebStorm errors]

and when it's rune by Node, Node doesn't recognise the rest expression.

```
C:\PluralSight\TypeScript>node rest-parameter.js
C:\PluralSight\TypeScript\rest-parameter.js:5
var foo = (...myParams) => {
           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @squint Cool link.  Node just doesn't support them.  C'est la vive.

Comment: @BanksySan if you change typescript to [target ES5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) it will work

Comment: Cheers @DavidSherret, can I do that in WebStorm?  It's be less hassle that having to use tsc at the command line.

Comment: @BanksySan you should look into using a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html) file—specify `"target": "ES5"` under `"compilerOptions"`. WebStorm should support that.

Comment: That sounds better.  Cheers @DavidSherret

Answer (score 3):

As a side note regarding node.

It does support rest parameters in 5.x version. They are not enabled by default alongside with plenty other es6 goodies.

To enable them run node with `--harmony` parameter or if some of features are still work in progress - explicitly enable them with corresponding flags. For example:

```
node --harmony --harmony_default_parameters app.js
```

Use the following command to see all of such 'in progress' ones:

```
node --v8-options | grep 'in progress'
```

Comment: Should `node --harmony --harmony_default_parameters` be  `node --harmony --harmony_rest_parameters`?

Comment: Is there a way to enable all the bleeding edge tech?

Comment: No - for rest parameters its enough to have --harmony. As they are not `in progress`. So to get bleeding edge use --harmony and all 'in progress' params (its not so many) specified manually